# lm_robust() generates "Error in FUN(...): operator needs one or two arguments" but results seem correct

Tags: r, lm

Without the ability to post the actual or sandbox data (apologies), I am running the following model using a sample of about 1,000,000 observations, about 150 factor levels (X4 = calendar time dummies), and about 600 clusters (X5 = cross sectional units):

```
lm  <- lm_robust(Y ~ X1+X2+X3+as.factor(X4), cluster = X5, df)
```

which generates the following error

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ..., rstudio.notebook.executing = FALSE) : 
  operator needs one or two arguments
```

What I don't understand is why `summary(lm)` generates an output that does seem reasonable. And my internet search has not resulted in anything posted that addresses or references this issue.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on or where I could look for what generates this error. Or is there another model I should use?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I am wondering if this is a version issue. I am running R 4.1.0 and package estimatr version 0.30.4. I'll update this post if updating both resolves the issue.

Comment: The other thing you could provide us/do to help track down the error is to run `traceback()` after you get the error. The `rstudio.notebook.executing` argument seems pretty strange though. Are you running under RStudio/do you get the same error if you run in a plain R console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using again RStudio 2021.09.3, but now estimating the above regression under R 4.1.2 with the updated package estimatr version 0.30.6, there were no errors. As a matter of fact, none of the many similar models I then subsequently estimated had an issue.

At this point, I assume that there must have been some incompatibilities between some package versions and/or R 4.1.0 and updating R and the packages resolved the problem.